# Does the datamapper convert the SGBD result as an object?

Tags: php, model-view-controller

I am working with MySql and results/rows are returned within an array.

I do understand that in the end, the model layer "goal" is to return an object once the SGBD query is processed.

So, should the process of converting rows (or a single row) into an object be integrated in the DataMapper (which is part of the Model layer) or should it be the responsibility of a third service that would be injected in the DataMapper?

Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> So, should the process of converting rows (or a single row) into an
>   object be integrated in the DataMapper.

Well yes it's the responsibility of the data mapper. It should return an entity, not a result set.

> or should it be the responsibility of a third service that would be injected in the DataMapper?

This is also a possibility, google to "UnitOfWork" I think that's what you are looking for. 
https://www.sitepoint.com/implementing-a-unit-of-work/

You can also take a look at the doctrine source 
https://github.com/doctrine/doctrine2/blob/master/lib/Doctrine/ORM/EntityManager.php

Answer (score 0):

It is better to return the object from model to controller, because whenever you need **result or row** can go through each of them needed.